# Memory Usage Monitoring in GCP Compute Engine with or without Stack Driver

Tags: memory, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, stackdriver, resource-utilization

Cloud Platform - **GCP Compute Engine**

OS - **Ubuntu, 16.04 LTS**

**I want to see memory utilization graph** just like CPU utilization (compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization).

I could not find any way to monitor my Compute Engine memory utilization even if Stack-driver is enabled.

I checked https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute and there is no endpoint for memory utilization monitoring.

I tried stackdriver agent monitoring endpoints also but it is not working ( `agent.googleapis.com/memory/percent_used`) 
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-memory.

Does anyone know how can I see memory utilization graph in GCP compute engine instance monitoring or via Stack Driver Monitoring

Comment: This article has tips on installing Stackdriver and how to debug: https://www.jhanley.com/google-compute-stackdriver-logging-installation-setup-debugging/

Comment: @JohnHanley the linkt to your website is not working ..

Comment: @c69 - I have received similar reports but I cannot figure this out. I am on my website right now updating an article. Site monitoring shows no downtime. My site is not down and is not overloaded and has constant traffic every second (170,000 views in the past month). This remains a mystery to me.

Comment: offtopic: ping works, but Chrome does not open the URL, even the root one.

Comment: @c69 Website issue solved. IPv6 misconfiguration issue for an old load balancer.

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED**

- **On Stackdriver Monitoring**: (You will have to install the agent on your VM Instance)

  1. Install the Stackdriver Monitoring Agent following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#joint-install).
  2. Open stackdriver monitoring API by clicking Navigation Menu -> Stackdriver -> Monitoring
  3. Once you are there on the left side you will click on "Resources" -> Metric explorer.
  4. On resource type: GCE VM Instance / Metrics: "Memory usage" and/or "Memory utilization".
  5. On filter, select Name, Value: (Name of your instance) 
     You should see now the graphic metrics of the Memory utilization.

Comment: It's not about CPU but about memory!

Answer (score 2):

You missed something in the [installation of the stackdriver agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#joint-install). I just tested and it works like a charm on ubuntu 16.04 (Standard Google Image)!

Then go to stackdriver

- Resources -> Instances: You should see your VM instance
  [image]
- Click on your instance -> click on Agent -> Scroll down and you see your memory and your swap usage

[image]